# How to Fix Importing Appium Libary Module Not Found in VS Code because Python Path

Tags: python, appium, robotframework, python-appium

I just learned Automation Testing using Robot Framework in Python. I have error where in VS Code can't find python path library. I imported AppiumLibrary but the VS Code can't define them. And when I run my testcase, i found the error based in the picture which I had attached and I attach my Pip List too. Hope everybody can help me for the solution. Thank you.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Template robot main suite.

Library             AppiumLibrary
Library             RPA.Browser
```

[image: Error Description]

[image: Pip List]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working with a virtual environment, and install the required libraries.

1. create the virtual environment. run from the terminal: `python -m venv ./venv`
2. activate the virtual env. run from the terminal: `./venv/scripts/activate`
3. install pip dependencies. Based on your test screenshot, you need Appium library and the RPA.
   run: `pip install robotframework-appiumlibrary` and then `pip install rpaframework` and `pip install robotframework-browser` ([Additional RPA installation](https://rpaframework.org/#installation)).